# Visual Studio launch feedback application not found

Tags: visual-studio

### Environment

- Windows 10 Pro 22H2
- Visual Studio 2022: `17.9.1` and `17.9.3`

### Issue

When I tried to launch the feedback of VS by clicking any buttons in `Help`-`Send Feedbck`,it would throw out a error window: `Application not found`.

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: Visual studio is trying to open this link in a browser - so you could start by trying to access http://go.microsoft.com directly from your browser to check if you are able to reach it

Comment: Thank you. I found out the result for your answer

Answer (score 0):

These feedback buttons are simple. Open the default browser and open the link in the error window.

`Application not found` means it cannot find the default browser. So, check the `Default Apps` setting -`Web browser`. I solved this issue by this method.